# Вызов функции из функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Тупой, наверное, вопрос, но я не могу сообразить.

Есть некий код :

```
def test1():
    def test2():
        #Тело нашей функции
```

И вот как мне вызвать **test2**? Заранее спасибо :3

Comment: Уточните из какой области видимости вы собираетесь вызывать Ваш код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам необходимо вызвать функцию `test2` из глобальной области видимости, то это невозможно.
Она является локальным объектом функции `test1` и доступна только в контексте исполнения этой функции.

Если же Вы хотите вызвать её в теле функции `test1`, то это тривиально.

***Пример:***

```py
def test1():
    def test2():
        pass

    test2()    # Так можно

test2()        # Так нельзя!
test1.test2()  # Так нельзя!
```

Comment: @AzikAzimov Если ответ Вам помог, то пометьте его как правильный, пожалуйста.

Comment: Через 6 минут смогу

Answer (score 1):

Функцию `test2` можно вызвать, если ее вернуть из первой функции. Типичный способ применения - создание "замыкания" (closure): `test2` будет помнить состояние локальных переменных (в том числе аргументов) функции `test1`.

```
def test1(name):
    def test2():
        print("Hello, {}!".format(name))
    return test2

t1 = test1("Username1")
t2 = test1("Username2")

t1()  # Hello, Username1!
t2()  # Hello, Username2!
```